# Почему Wp-Super-Cache Wordpress не работает с NGINX/PHP-FM?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Помогите пожалуйста, не работает Wp-super-cache, не кэширует вообще, ноль файлов.
Centos7, Nginx/PHP-FM, VestaCP, Wordpress Multisite на поддоменах.

Все работает, nginx запускается, но Wp-Super-Cache не кэширует.
Проверка кэширования файлы делает тестовые, но пишет: Страницы не совпадают! Временной штамп отличается или не был найден!

Вот мой темплейт nginx:

```
server {
listen      %ip%:%web_ssl_port%;
server_name %domain_idn% %alias_idn%;
root        %docroot%;
index       index.php index.html index.htm;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/%domain%.log combined;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/%domain%.bytes bytes;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/%domain%.error.log error;
ssl         on;
ssl_certificate      %ssl_pem%;
ssl_certificate_key  %ssl_key%;


set $cache_uri $request_uri;


# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}



# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php


               |wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php
                  |wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php |sitemap(_index)?.xml
                  |[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {


    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}



# Don't use the cache for logged-in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+
                     |wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $cache_uri 'null cache';
}



# Set the cache file
set $cachefile "/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html";
set $gzipcachefile "/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html.gz";
if ($https ~* "on") {
    set $cachefile "/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index-https.html";
    set $gzipcachefile "/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html.gz";
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
}

location / {
# Try in the following order: (1) gzipped cachefile, (2) cachefile, (3) normal url, (4) php
    try_files $gzipcachefile $cachefile $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
        expires     max;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

    fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_cache microcache;
    fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 30s;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;   

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return  404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass    %backend_lsnr%;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
error_page  403 /error/404.html;
error_page  404 /error/404.html;
error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

location /error/ {
    alias   %home%/%user%/web/%domain%/document_errors/;
}

location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
    deny    all;
    return  404;
}

if ($http_user_agent ~ "Python-urllib|Spinn3r|SISTRIX|Morfeus|Toata|QuerySeekerSpider|JikeSpider|proximic|Sosospider|Sogou web spider|aesop_com_spiderman|alexibot|backweb|batchftp|bigfoot|black.hole|blackwidow|blowfish|botalot|buddy|builtbottough|bullseye|cheesebot|cherrypicker|chinaclaw|collector|copier|copyrightcheck|cosmos|crescent|custo|da|diibot|disco|dittospyder|dragonfly|drip|easydl|ebingbong|ecatch|eirgrabber|emailcollector|emailsiphon|emailwolf|erocrawler|exabot|eyenetie|filehound|flashget|flunky|frontpage|getright|getweb|go.?zilla|go-ahead-got-it|gotit|grabnet|grafula|harvest|hloader|hmview|httplib|httrack|humanlinks|ilsebot|infonavirobot|infotekies|intelliseek|interget|iria|jennybot|jetcar|joc|justview|jyxobot|kenjin|keyword|larbin|leechftp|lexibot|lftp|libweb|likse|linkscan|linkwalker|lnspiderguy|lwp|magnet|mag-net|markwatch|mata.hari|memo|microsoft.url|midown.tool|miixpc|mirror|missigua|mister.pix|moget|mozilla.newt|nameprotect|navroad|backdoorbot|nearsite|net.?vampire|netants|netcraft|netmechanic|netspider|nextgensearchbot|attach|nicerspro|nimblecrawler|npbot|octopus|offline.?explorer|offline.navigator|openfind|outfoxbot|pagegrabber|papa|pavuk|pcbrowser|php.?version.?tracker|pockey|propowerbot|prowebwalker|psbot|pump|queryn|recorder|realdownload|reaper|reget|true_robot|repomonkey|rma|internetseer|sitesnagger|siphon|slysearch|smartdownload|snake|snapbot|snoopy|sogou|spacebison|spankbot|spanner|sqworm|superbot|superhttp|surfbot|asterias|suzuran|szukacz|takeout|teleport|telesoft|the.intraformant|thenomad|tighttwatbot|titan|urldispatcher|turingos|turnitinbot|urly.warning|vacuum|vci|voideye|whacker|libwww-perl|widow|wisenutbot|wwwoffle|xaldon|xenu|zeus|zyborg|anonymouse|zip|emaile|enhancer|fetch|go.?is|auto|bandit|clip|copier|master|sauger|site.quester|whack|craftbot|download|extract|stripper|sucker|ninja|clshttp|webspider|leacher|grabber|webpictures|Jakarta|libwww|lwp-trivial|PHPCrawl|WEP Search|Missigua Locator|ISC Systems iRc|Aboundex|360Spider|Java|Cogentbot|BunnySlippers|Cegbfeieh|AIBOT|Demon|Devil|Wonder|Foobot|Kenjin Spider|Density|LinkextractorPro|LWP::Simple|MassDownloader|Mass Downloader|NetZIP|NG|Metasearch|WebFetch|WebCopier|Webclipping|WebBandit|WebAuto|WebGo|Web.Image.Collector|WebLeacher|WebmasterWorldForumBot|WebReaper|WebSauger|eXtractor|Webster|WebStripper|WebWhacker|WebZIP|Catall Spider|AcoiRobot|rogerbot|MJ12bot|Ahrefsbot|dobot|MegaIndex.ru|SemrushBot|LinkpadBot|Zite|TweetmemeBot|woriobot|topsy|js-kit|NING") {return 403;}

location /vstats/ {
    alias   %home%/%user%/web/%domain%/stats/;
    include %home%/%user%/web/%domain%/stats/auth.conf*;
}

include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

include     %home%/%user%/conf/web/nginx.%domain_idn%.conf*;

}
```

---

В общем никто не помогает )
Я попробовал WpSuperCache, CacheEnabler, Litespeed plugin, Breeze.

Короче работает прямо после установки без танцев только Breeze.
Cache Enabler технически понравился, но завести его не удалось.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш конфиг не смотрел. Только что проверил на новом сайте с таким конфигом:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log debug;

    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
    index index.php;

    set $cache_uri $request_uri;

    # POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }   
    if ($query_string != "") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }   

    # Don't cache uris containing the following segments
    if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }   

    # Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_logged_in") {
        set $cache_uri 'null cache';
    }

    # Use cached or actual file if they exists, otherwise pass request to WordPress
    location / {
        try_files /wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html $uri $uri/ /index.php ;
    }    

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404; 
        include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # Cache static files for as long as possible
    location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        expires max; log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
}
```

Всё завелось с первого раза. Не забудьте перезагрузить сервер.

Comment: Спасибо! Но наверно пробовать не буду уже. Поставил плагин Breeze, работает. Правда пока без     # Use cached or actual file if they exists, otherwise pass request to WordPress